# Как преобразовать строку в 16-ричную строку либо в массив byte?

Tags: c#, строки

К примеру у меня есть строка типа:

```
"796173767265"
```

мне бы хотелось перевести её в 16-ричный формат, либо в массив **byte**.

Этот вопрос является вольным переводом [вот этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999604/convert-string-to-hex-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала вам нужно поместить его в `byte[]`, так что сделайте это:

```
 byte[] ba = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("sample");
```

и получив массив байт превратите его в строку:

```
var hexString = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
```

hexString вернёт строку с черточками ( - ), так что надо убрать лишние символы из строки:

```
 hexString = hexString.Replace("-", "");
```

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ: вы можете использовать другой метод `Encoding` если вам нужно.

---

```
 var result = string.Join("", 
               input.Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("X2")));
```

Либо

```
 var result =string.Join("", 
              input.Select(c=> String.Format("{0:X2}", Convert.ToInt32(c))
```

---

Пример для Unicode:

```
public class HexadecimalEncoding
{
    public static string ToHexString(string str)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
        foreach (var t in bytes)
        {
            sb.Append(t.ToString("X2"));
        }

        return sb.ToString(); // returns: "48656C6C6F20776F726C64" for "Hello world"
    }

    public static string FromHexString(string hexString)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
        for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
        }

        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes); // returns: "Hello world" for "48656C6C6F20776F726C64"
    }
}
```

---

Этот функция подходит для длинных строк:

```
private string StringToHex(string hexstring)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char t in hexstring)
    { 
        //Note: X for upper, x for lower case letters
        sb.Append(Convert.ToInt32(t).ToString("x")); 
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

использование:

```
 string result = StringToHex("Hello world"); //returns "48656c6c6f20776f726c64"
```

Другой подход в одной строке

```
string input = "Hello world";
string result = String.Concat(input.Select(x => ((int)x).ToString("x")));
```

---

Не сколько вариантов Unicode

```
 var s = "0";

var s1 = string.Concat(s.Select(c => $"{(int)c:x4}"));  // left padded with 0 - "0030d835dfcfd835dfdad835dfe5d835dff0d835dffb"

var sL = BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s)).Replace("-", "");       // Little Endian "300035D8CFDF35D8DADF35D8E5DF35D8F0DF35D8FBDF"
var sB = BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(s)).Replace("-", ""); // Big Endian "0030D835DFCFD835DFDAD835DFE5D835DFF0D835DFFB"

// no encodding "300035D8CFDF35D8DADF35D8E5DF35D8F0DF35D8FBDF"
byte[] b = new byte[s.Length * sizeof(char)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(s.ToCharArray(), 0, b, 0, b.Length);

var sb = BitConverter.ToString(b).Replace("-", "");
```

---

Сам пользуюсь таким способом :

```
byte value5 = Convert.ToByte(new string(stroka_t), 16);
```

Также очень помогло [Руководство по C#  docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-between-hexadecimal-strings-and-numeric-types)